# A question about the definition of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, extension-field

In the usual definition of the field $\mathbb{C}$, as $\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$, the field $\mathbb{R}$ is not exactly a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, but only an isomorphic copy of the subfield $\{(a,0):a\in\mathbb{R}\}$. I am wondering: can we define $\mathbb{C}$ as 
the set 
$$
\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\ \text{and}\ b\neq0\}\ ?
$$
In this case, how to define the operations?

$\mathbf{Remark}$: We know that the operations of $\{(a,0)\}$ can be extend to 
$\{(a,b)\}$. Since $\mathbb{R}≅\{(a,0)\}$, can we prove that the operations of $\mathbb{R}$ can be extend to $\mathbb{R}∪\{(a,b):b≠0\}$?

Comment: Of course you can, but then you'd have to define the operations by splitting into cases (real vs. non-real), which would be incredibly tedious...

Comment: Thanks Hans, but is there any way to go around this? for example: We know that the operations of $\{(a,0)\}$ can be extend to $\{(a,b)\}$. Since $\mathbb{R}\cong\{(a,0)\}$, can we prove that the operations of $\mathbb{R}$ can be extend to $\mathbb{R}\cup\{(a,b):b\neq0\}$?

Comment: Note that this is a frequent phenomenon. It happens when constucting the inetegrs from the natural numbers, the rationals from the integers, the reals from the rationals. And is the constant polynomial $42$ the same thing as the real number $42$? It is common to identify the original structure with its image in the larger one.

Comment: @boaz: I thought you wanted to avoid identifying $\mathbb{R}$ with its isomorphic subfield. If you do that, you can get around it, as shown in egreg's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without any difficulty. Consider the map
$$
f\colon\mathbb{R}\cup\underbrace{\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R},b\ne0\}}_{X}
\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}
$$
defined in the obvious way:
$$
f\colon a\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto(a,0),
\qquad
f\colon (a,b)\in X\mapsto(a,b),
$$
and define the operations on $\mathbb{R}\cup X$ by
$$
u+v=f^{-1}(f(u)+f(v)),
\qquad
uv=f^{-1}(f(u)f(v))
$$

However, it is dubious if you gain something with respect to identifying $a$ with $(a,0)$ and setting $i=(0,1)$, so
$$
(a,b)=(a,0)+(b,0)(0,1)=a+bi
$$

Comment: A very nice solution. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can instead define $\mathbb{C}$ by

$$\mathbb{C} := \mathbb{R}(i) = \{a + bi \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

where $i^2 = -1$.

Then this is the typical definition of $\mathbb{C}$ and is a field since $i$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ by taking $b=0$.

Comment: This is not good, because you use in this definition two operation "+" and "$\cdot$" that are not defined (what is $1+i$ ?)

Comment: @boaz, this are trivial field operation over $\mathbb R$. $1,i$ are basis elements.

Comment: This is correct, but you need to append the definition $i^2 = -1$ for this formulation of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: In order to define an operation you need first to specify the set it define on, not the opposite way....in this example, you define the operations "$\cdot$" and "$+$" before defining $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Sure, I was being terse because the operations are the expected ones. In fact, in writing $\mathbb{C}$ (versus, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$) you are implying those operations as well, are you not?

Comment: What set is $\mathbb{R}(i)$ exactly?

Comment: It is not clear to me if you think your edit answered my query. It does not. What is $i$ what is $7i$?

Comment: @quid I wasn't trying to answer your question with the edit :) I confused myself with what I was saying. Can you be more explicit about what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that you do not say what $i$ is. I think what you are trying to do is say that $\mathbb{C}$ is the/an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus it contains $\mathbb{R}$. But if you run through  the construction of the alg closure, there is exactly the same issue there.

Comment: @quid Do you disagree that $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}(i)$ where $i^2 = -1$? Also is there a problem with saying that taking $b=0$ gives you a copy of $\mathbb{R}$? I'm not appealing anywhere to the algebraic closure, at least I didn't think I was...

Comment: What do you mean by  $i$ precisely?

Comment: I think the main objection from @quid is that when you define new things you have to define them in terms of old things. The way you define $\mathbb{C}$ involves an element of $\mathbb{C}$ namely $i$. The way to avoid $i$ is the technique of modern algebra which I have given in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer, but it is too long for a comment.

---

The traditional construction of $\mathbb{C}$ as an ordered pair of real numbers is the simplest approach possible. But this appears to have to have very non-intuitive definition of multiplication of pairs.

A better approach is the one given by *Modern Algebra*. Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the set of all polynomials with real coefficients. Let's say that *two polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ are congruent to each other modulo another polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ if both $f(x), g(x)$ leave the same remainder when divided by $p(x)$ or in other words when $p(x) \mid f(x) - g(x)$* and we write $$f(x)\equiv g(x)\pmod{p(x)}$$ Here we assume $p(x)$ to be of positive degree. This relation of congruence is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Let's fix a polynomial $p(x)$ of positive degree and consider the set of all polynomials congruent to $f(x)$ modulo $p(x)$: $$[f(x)] = \{g(x)\mid g(x)\equiv f(x)\pmod{p(x)}\}$$ Such sets are called equivalence classes and we can define operations of $+$ and $\times$ on these these equivalence classes by $$[f(x)] + [g(x)] = [f(x) + g(x)], [f(x)]\times[g(x)] = [f(x)\times g(x)]$$ And now consider the set of all such equivalence classes $$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle = \{[f(x)]\mid f(x) \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ The magic happens when $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial and then it can be proved that the above set forms a field. Moreover this field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ if $p(x)$ is of degree $1$.

The field of complex numbers is now given by $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^{2} + 1 \rangle$, thus it is the set of equivalence classes modulo the irreducible polynomial $x^{2} + 1$. By convention we denote the equivalence class containing $f(x)$ by the symbol $[r(x)]$ where $r(x)$ is the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $p(x)$. So in case of $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^{2} + 1\rangle$ the elements of $\mathbb{C}$ look like $[a + bx]$ (the remainder is always of degree $1$ or less if we divide by $x^{2} + 1$). The sum and product of elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are defined by $$[a + bx] + [c + dx] = [a + c + (b + d)x], [a + bx][c + dx] = [(a + bx)(c + dx)]$$ Let's see what happens when we try to find the remainder when $(a + bx)(c + dx)$ is divided by $x^{2} + 1$.

We have $$(a + bx)(c + dx) = ac + bdx^{2} + (ad + bc)x = (ac - bd) + (ad + bc)x + bd(x^{2} + 1)$$ and thus the remainder is $(ac - bd) + (ad + bc)x$. It follows that $$[a + bx][c + dx] = [(a + bx)(c + dx)] = [ac - bd + (ad + bc)x]$$ This definition of complex numbers can be transformed into the usual one by replacing symbol $[a + bx]$ by $(a, b)$ and we can see now the justification of multiplication rule $$(a, b)(c, d) = (ac - bd, ad + bc)$$ BTW in case you have not guessed the element $[x] \in \mathbb{C}$ is denoted by special symbol $i$ and it has the property $i^{2} + [1] = [0]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. Then there are different possibilities:

1. $a \in \mathbb{R}, b = (x,y), y \neq 0$: $a + b := (a+x, y)$.
2. $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$: $a + b$ is obvious.
3. $a = (x_1, y_1), b = (x_2, y_2), y_1 \neq 0 \neq y_2$: $a + b := (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2)$ if $y_1 + y_2 \neq 0$ and $x_1 + x_2$ otherwise.
4. $a = (x,y), b \in \mathbb{R}$: As in 1.

You could make the same for multiplication. Anyway: This is stupid and useless.

Comment: I agree, but as i wrote after @Hans Lundmark comment, can we bypass that?

Comment: why do you want to do it this way anyway? And how do you want to bypass this. We have "different" objects in your definition of $\mathbb{C}$. I don't see a way to unify them.