# Deriving Complex Multiplication using Only the Field Axioms alone (is it possible?)

Tags: abstract-algebra

The complex multiplication rule is usually posited as a definition, *a priori*. Where the rule is,

$(a,b)(a',b')=(aa'-bb', ab'+ba')$,

I wonder however, if we can derive this rule using the field axioms alone.

Where here, we also conceive of the complex field $\mathbb{C}$ as equivalent to the field $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The motivation behind doing this stems from how arbitrary this 2-tuple multiplication rule appears. This rule only makes sense if we have some background conception of $z=a+bi$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. But strictly speaking, the definition of a complex number as an ordered pair has no conception of $\sqrt{-1}$.

The derivation I've read so far utilizes the 'definition' $(0,1)\times(0,1)=(-1,0)$ alongside the field axioms. But again, this draws on some conception of $i^2=-1$, and I was hoping to do without it.

Thanks!

Comment: should be: (0,1)x(0,1)=(-1,0)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my mistake, I'll edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the multiplication can certainly be defined in other ways (think of identifying $(0,1)$ with $2i$ instead of $i$ for example).

Comment: Here is just a thought: the rule $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,-(ad+bc))$ also makes $\mathbb{C}$ into a field. In fact, using the axiom of choice you can produce other field authomorphisms of the complex numbers which will give you another " field structure". So I doubt you can derive this from field axioms alone.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this has been answered on our site already. Anyway, if you have a field, call it $K$, that contains the reals, and is also a 2-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, then you get $K=\Bbb{C}$. Always. Pick any element $\omega\in K, \omega\notin\Bbb{R}$. The three elements $1,\omega,\omega^2$ are then necessarily linearly independent. So $\omega$ is a zero of a quadratic $p(x)$. Its discriminant cannot be $\ge0$, for then $\omega$ would be real. If the discriminant is negative, you get, after adjusting for the (real) factor $\sqrt{-D}$, first $i$ then the complex numbers.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't a field (fourth line) . . .

Comment: $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$ follows from the distributive property, combining like terms, and the definitional fact that $i^2=-1$. I don't understand why or in what sense you would hope for a motivation for the multiplication in $\mathbb{R}[i]$ which is ignorant about what $i$ even is.

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1841462/72031 for a proper justification of the product rule of complex numbers.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, thanks!! This looks helpful, I'll definitely study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I begin with the phrase: "Choices were made!". You want to make $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a field without using the definition $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(-1,0)$ and only the field axioms. But then there are several ways to do this. You already described one of them, namely:

$$ (a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc). $$

Here is another one:

$$ (a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,-(ad+bc)). $$

The second one corresponds to the field automorphism $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ which sends a complex number $(a,b)$ to $(a,-b)$. Also known as complex conjugation.

There are lot's of other field automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ called wild automorphisms, see for example [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PaulBYale.pdf). Each of them gives you another field structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Unfortunately they are not constructive and require the axiom of choice, so I cant really write them down. But from this you can see that you need some further assumption to get the field structure you initially wanted.

Comment: Yea this it makes it clear now too: that it isn't possible to define the canocial complex multiplication rule from the field axioms, as these axioms allow for other multiplication rules.